# Django Framework : Problems with views settings

Tags: python, django, django-views

im learning Django framework and having some issues that i dont get it.

Actually i have apps like Polls/ Blog/ and my homepage/ installed and working as i want.

My problem is to display each data into my homepage_index.html like :

_ how many Question my polls contain

_ how many Article my blog contain

Both of informations are from different apps.

From Django Tutorial i found a solution to display by example my last 3 Question.objects like this.

homepage/views.py :

```
from django.views import generic
from django.utils import timezone
from polls.models import Question


class homepage(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'homepage/homepage_index.html'
    context_object_name = 'latest_question_list'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Question.objects.filter(pub_date__lte=timezone.now()).order_by('-pub_date')[:3]
```

my homepage_index.html working :

```
 {% if latest_question_list %}
     <ul>
        {% for question in latest_question_list %}
            <li><a style="color: white; text-decoration: none;" href="{% url 'polls:detail.html' question.id %}">{{ question.question_text }}</a></li>
        {% endfor %}
     </ul>
{% else %}
     <p>No polls are available.</p>
{% endif %}
```

How can i define in my homepage/views.py with multiple context_object_name and multiple queryset please ?

I tryied to read many documentations but im still failing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find more detail at the offical docs, what you need to do is same as the `now` value in the demo.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#listview

you need to override get_context_data

1. calculate the number of questions or blogs, or other datas, put them into context
2. and then render the number at `homepage_index.html` .

Comment: Thanks for your help, im still trying to do it ^^

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution without override the get_context_data but i solved half of my problem.( i fail to use the override get_context_data method).
Right now i can display multiple informations i wanted in my homepage_index.html like this :

```
from blog.models import Article
from polls.models import Question

from django.shortcuts import render

def homepage(request):
    list_of_title_article = Article.objects.all()
    list_of_title_question = Question.objects.all()

    return render(request, 'homepage_index.html',  {'latest_question_list': list_of_title_question, 'latest_article_list': list_of_title_article})
```

It look working as i want but i still dont have any counter method of my objects.

Right now im trying to use Question.objects.all().count() and i have no context to deliver into the render(request, ...)